# Virtual resolution screenshot

Tags: screenshot, resolution

Is there a program for windows where I can increase the size of a window (not a browser) to a resolution beyond the limits of my screen (say 50,000 x 500) and then take a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

HI,

some time ago I used this portabble programm,
I hope You are using Windows and not an Unix-like system.

http://www.winresizer.com/

It dosen't make screenshots itself...